# DateAdd() returns faulty Date in SQL Server Reporting Services

Tags: ssrs-2008, dateadd

I have a report that takes a date as a parameter.

If I use `=Parameters!Date.Value`, the report runs fine.

However, if I use `=DateAdd("d", 1, Parameters!Date.Value)`, the report is left blank, even though the formats are exactly the same:[image: screenshot of what this looks like]. (Note: it simply cannot run. It's not that there are no values to return as the field names don't return either.)

---

I have also tried  `=DateAdd(DateInterval.Date, 1, Parameters!Date.Value)`

`=DateAdd("d", 1, Parameters!Date.Value)`

`=DateValue(FormatDateTime(DateAdd("d", 1, Parameters!Date.Value), DateFormat.ShortDate ))` and many variations thereof but I can't seem to crack it!

---

### Update

If I use `DateInterval.Month` instead of `DateInterval.Day` then the date is still incremented as desired (12/22/2010) but the table shows up! Interesting how my local settings are *dd-mm-yyyy* and these dates are *mm-dd-yyyy*.

Comment: @marc_s Oops! My mistake. Apologies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing the locale of the report to EN-GB (I'm assuming you're in the UK), as the report might be getting confused between different date formats.

Comment: Thanks, this helped a bit. I have edited my original question with what's happening now :)

Comment: Disregard that, I had made a mistake. The en-GB change worked!